# Tossing a coin around $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: pr.probability, expectation

**Motivation.** With my younger son I played the following game on a big (dysfunctional) clock which can be modelled as $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$ : Put the clock hands at number $12 ( = 0)$. Toss a coin, and move the clock hands to the right (i.e. from $n$ to $n+1 \text{ mod } 12$) if the coin toss was tails, and move the clock hands in the other way otherwise.

The procedure ends, when the clock hands have been at every of the $12$ positions of the clock.

**Question.** In terms of $n$, what is the expected number of moves until this game ends?

Comment: Isn’t this just a simple Markov chain problem? It doesn’t really seem research level. Also, what do you mean by “in terms of $n$?”

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda This is certainly a Markov chain but I don't think that it is all that simple.  You have to keep track of the set of numbers that have already been visited (which is a circular arc) as well as the current position.  You can factor out the rotational symmetry but that still leaves $\binom{n}{2}+1$ states for the game on $\mathbb{Z}/n$.

Comment: In my view, a more interesting question is the surprisingly uniform distribution of the final position

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Suppose you are at position $a$, and have already visited $\{a-i,\dotsc,a,\dotsc,a+j\}$, where $i,j\geq 0$ and $i+j<n$.  The expected time $t_{ij}$ until you have covered the whole clock must satisfy $t_{i,n-1-i}=0$ and
$$ t_{ij} = \frac{1}{2}t_{(i-1)_+,\;j+1}+\frac{1}{2}t_{i+1,\;(j-1)_+}+1 $$
(where $k_+$ means $\max(0,k)$).  The solution is
$$ t_{ij} = \frac{1}{2}\left(n(n-1)-i(i+1)-j(j+1)\right)$$
In particular, the expected time from the obvious starting position is $t_{00}=n(n-1)/2$.

Comment: Indeed, this is a classic example of the cover time of a random walk on a graph. See [Example 11.1 in this book](https://pages.uoregon.edu/dlevin/MARKOV/markovmixing.pdf) and other cool stuff there.